# How to save and load vocabulary_ from a CountVectorizer?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science

I have a class in which I create a countVectorizer and create vectors with fit_transform. This generates a vocabulary_.
I would like to have this CountVectorizer with the vocabulary in one file to be able to reuse it in another class.
Does anyone have any advice for me? I already tried to do the whole thing with save_npz. But it didn't work properly.

Here's my function as I've tried to save the whole thing. I'm not sure if this is the right one.

```
...
count_vect = CountVectorizer()
...

def vectorizeData():

  clean_data = pd.read_feather('../working/' + PROJECT + '_clean.feather') 

  word_count = count_vect.fit_transform(clean_data.text)

  scipy.sparse.save_npz('../working/' + PROJECT + '_countVec.npz', word_count)
```

and the load

```
def ModelData():
  ...
  count_vect_test = scipy.sparse.load_npz('../working/' + PROJECT + '_countVec.npz')
  ...
```

after the load I have only the csr_matrix, but not the CountVectorizer object.

Comment: Have you considered creating a `CountVectorizer` and then simply assigning to its `vocabulary_` attribute? Otherwise you can Pickle it, although Pickle is fragile and for that reason suboptimal.

Comment: ho can i  assing an existing vocabulary_?

Comment: It's just a python object. `vectorizer = CountVectorizer(); vectorizer.vocabulary_ = my_vocab`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using joblib?

https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/joblib.dump.html

```
import joblib

# example for saving python object as pkl
joblib.dump(vectorizer, "vectorizer.pkl")

# loading pickled vectorizer
vectorizer = joblib.load("vectorizer.pkl")
```